# How is autofill_compat_mode_allowed_packages in Android pre populated and how can I add my own app to the list

Tags: android, adb

With "adb shell settings get global autofill_compat_mode_allowed_packages" you can see all the whitelisted apps that require compatibility mode for the autofill service.

I'm wondering how that list gets pre populated.

I am not able to find any documentation about this list.

I have two queries mentioned below:

1. how can I add my own app to this list without using "adb shell settings put global autofill_compat_mode_allowed_packages pkg1[resId1]:pkg2[resId1,resId2]" all the time as it requires root access?
2. Is there any way to do that programmatically, i.e. once my app starts it will be added to the whitelist. It seems like this list is a predefined list from Android. Am I right?

Looking forward for to some inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
adb shell settings put global autofill_compat_mode_allowed_packages pkg1[resId1]:pkg2[resId1,resId2]
```

See here for more information [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-services).